# Mysql UNION way to differ from which table result row is

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union, union-all

Lets say I have below query.

```
SELECT City FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT City FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City;
```

Lest say there is one same city NY in both tables witch will give me:

```
| City     |
| -------- | 
| NY       |
| NY       |
```

I am fetching this in a HTML table, is there a way to differ from witch MySQL table result row is from, other then making another column in tables itself, for example column `type`.

Maybe is possible to append something to result set itself in query?

Comment: Your query cannot be returning that result.  You are using `union` which removes duplicates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand your results, because `union` removes duplicates, so it should produce only one row.

If you want to include the table name, I would advise using `select distinct` and `union all`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'customers' as type, City FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 'suppliers' as type, City FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City;
```

Comment: You are right,  sorry, I tired to simplify it, query is much bigger and some columns like id's and case numbers witch is search term is the same. I am getting right results. But example is wrong.  I will accept this as its most correct with this remark so others reading don't get confused also.

Answer (score 2):

Append an extra column with the literal string value as the table name along with the existing query. This will help you to distinguish the rows.

```
SELECT 'Customers' as Type, City FROM Customers
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Suppliers' as Type, City FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City;
```

**Update:**
`UNION` removes the duplicate rows. So, if your tables have same values in the **City** column, it will return the unique rows. You have to use `UNION ALL`. This will return all rows and appending the string literal as the type column will help you to distinguish between the rows.

Thanks @Gordon for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Add an extra column containing a literal value depending on which subquery it is.

```
SELECT 'Customers' AS type, City
FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT 'Suppliers' AS type, City
FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY City, type
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add column in your query like following.

```
SELECT city, 'c' as type FROM Customers
UNION
SELECT city, 's' as type FROM Suppliers
ORDER BY city, type;
```